# How to add tvOS 12 simulator into Xcode 9.4.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, tvos

I'm working on big project which is currently being migrated to Xcode 10. But this process is still not finished and my app is crashing on tvOS 12 devices.

I was able to build the app on tvOS 12 device with Xcode 9.4.1 ( by copying of DeveloperDiskImage.dmg and DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature from Xcode 10 into Xcode 9.4.1 ). It's located at:

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/DeviceSupport/12.0 (16J364)

After moving 12.0 (16J364) folder into Xcode 9.4.1 ( and deleting that hash from the name of 11.4 folder ) I was able to build and debug the build on tvOS 12 device.

Now I need to build it also on simulator, I'm traveling now and I don't have access to Apple TV device. I've tried adding of simulators like it's described here:

https://medium.com/xcblog/simctl-control-ios-simulators-from-command-line-78b9006a20dc

But that new simulators with tvOS 12 appears only in Xcode 10. None of the simulator with tvOS 12 is available in Xcode 9.4.1 :-|

There is no folder like "DeviceSupport" in "AppleTVSimulator.platform" folder in Xcode, so I'm kind of stuck here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can build your application in Xcode 9. Then xcode-select to switch to Xcode 10, and use `xcrun simctl install` to install your .app bundle from the built products directory onto the newer simulator.

Comment: I've already updated project to Xcode 10, but it may work!